# Importing PDB (Protein Data Bank) files directly into Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, parsing, unreal-engine4, protein-database

I am building a project that will use Unreal Engine 4 to display protein models. Currently I cannot find a way to directly import PDB (Protein Data Bank) files directly into Unreal. Ideally I would like to have the PDB files converted into FBX files and stored inside the project. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why can't you convert your PDB file to FBX? Seems like that's the solution you want, no?

Comment: If you want to create 3D models from your protein models, Blender has an addon to view them and convert them to different formats see Atomic Blender (PDB/XYZ).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I have been able to successfully convert the PDBs in blender, however, I am looking for a solution that would allow users of my project to directly import PDBs without having to first convert them in another program.

Comment: Fair enough. You should add that to your description, to make things clearer though. The more information we have, the more we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pymol can export VRML files in wrl format for all kinds of visualization (even cartoons, not just atomic view).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbWXX.jpg

Unreal supports wrl import.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSEEkhiqABc

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).